# Simple JavaScript Bookmarklet not working on EDGE compatibility mode ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, bookmarklet

I am trying to run the following JavaScript as a test on a website / webapp*.

```
javascript: {window.alert("Hello World")}
```

*This website / webapp forces the EDGE browser to run on IE11 compatibility mode.

But am getting an error (translated to english) :

```
"No Access to Website: Make sure that the Webadress //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm?ErrorStatus=0x8007005# is correct".
```

The JS Code is now visible in the url section, so I assume the above error has not much to do with the actual problem.

**Tried it on Chrome and IE11 (native) and they both work with the mentioned website / webapp.**

Is there a way to make it work on EDGE compatibility mode IE11?

Thanks for your help!
KR
Joe

Comment: `trying to run the following JavaScript` - how exactly are you making this do anything in any web browser?

Comment: via a click on the bookmarklet (bookmark in browser favorites where the js code is placed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't make bookmarklet work in Edge IE mode as [IE mode doesn't support Internet Explorer toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-doesnt-support-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality).

[image]

From the image above, you can see that Favorites bar belongs to IE toolbars so you can't use it in Edge IE mode.

If you really need this feature in Edge IE mode, I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge browser. Edge team will check the feedbacks and improve the product continuously.

Comment: thanks for the provided information! is there a workaround to force the edge browser to not go into comp mode e.g. via startup parameter? 
unfortunately the browser config is set by company and one cannot change it via the regular menu / default browser setting (its set to enable comp mode and greyed out)

Comment: Found it:
create a shortcut to edge executable, add --ie-mode-test at the very end. by doing so you can force the browser to go into edge mode and the bookmarklet works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this question. Hopefully I can save someone the hours I spent debugging and thinking that Edge had removed Bookmarklet functionality.

While testing you should use the **Bookmarks** toolbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) instead of the **Favorites** sidebar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). Bookmarklets work when clicked on the Bookmarks toolbar and don't do anything when clicked from the Favorites sidebar.

I like the Favorites sidebar that stacks all the Favorites vertically on the right side. It has the same favorites as the Bookmarks toolbar in a different layout that shows more on wide screens. But I'll probably stop using it now that I know it doesn't support Bookmarklets.